# Hermite interpolation ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need help with the following task:

> Consider the IVP $y'=f(t,y), y(0)=y_0$ with $f:[0,T]\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\in C^3$ and Lipschitz continuous. Let $\mathcal T=\{0=t_1<\dots<t_n=T\}$ and $y_h$ a numerical solution of the IVP with order of convergence $p$.
>
> Let $\tilde{y}$ be the cubic Hermite spline for $y_h$ (this means $y_h(t_j)=\tilde{y}(t_j)$ and $f(t_j,y_h(t_j))=\tilde{y}'(t_j)$ for all $j=1,\dots n$).
>
> Determine $q$ so that $\|y(t)-\tilde{y}\|_\infty=\mathcal O(h^q)$.

I thought about using the theorem of Taylor. $f\in C^3$ means $y\in C^4$ and the third derivative of $\tilde{y}$ is constant. Does anyone have a idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

For the order $p$ of the numerical method to be applicable, you need that $f\in C^p$ to get the same error order in the application. If $f\in C^3$ and $p>3$, then the expected effective error order of the solution is still 3.

Practically it is rather hard to find examples that are substantially not $C^4$. What computer functions deliver are piecewise smooth functions that can have any kind of singularity at the interfaces, jumps, kinks, or just a lower smoothness order. So if this piecewise smooth function is overall $C^3$, and the solution crosses interfaces at isolated points, then the error order of the solution will effectively still be $4$ if the method has that or a higher order.

---

Hermite interpolation based on $(t_0,y_0,v_0),(t_1,y_1,v_1)$ can be approximated as Lagrange/Newton interpolation based on $(t_0,y_0),(t_0+h,y_0+hv_0),(t_1-h,y_1-hv_1),(t_1,y_1)$, $h$ small against $t_1-t_0$. The error formula there is more accessible as
$$
y(t)-\tilde y(t)=\frac{y^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!}(t-t_0)(t-t_0-h)(t-t_1+h)(t-t_1)
$$
So in the limit $h\to 0$
$$
|y(t)-\tilde y(t)|=\frac{|y^{(4)}(\xi)|}{4!}(t-t_0)^2(t-t_1)^2\le\frac{\|y^{(4)}\|}{16·4!}(t_1-t_0)^4
$$
For this to be valid you need $y\in C^4$, thus $f\in C^3$.

As the interpolation is linear in the input values, the error in these carries through as an addition to the interpolation error. So the overall error is $O((\Delta t)^{\min(4,p)})$.

Comment: why $|y(t)-\tilde{y(t)}|\leq \frac{y^{(4)}}{16\cdot 4!}(t_1-t_0)^4$? $\tilde{y}$ interpolates $y_h$ and not $y$.

Comment: Yes, you have 3 functions and thus 2 errors. It is easiest to compute the error from the exact solution to the cubic spline, and then between the cubic splines with exact and with numerical data. The first gives a maximum error of $h^4$, the second adds an error $h^p$.

Comment: I still don't understand why you get $|y-\tilde{y}|=\frac{\|y^{(4)}\|}{4!}(t_1-t_0)^4$. I think this error estimation is only valid if $\tilde{y}$ interpolates $y$. But this is not the case. @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was just too lazy to invent another symbol. One would probably have to set $\tilde y$ for the cubic spline from the exact solution and $\tilde y_h$ for the cubic spline from the numerical data. Then $\tilde y-y=O(h^4)$ and $\tilde y_h-\tilde y=O(h^p)$.

Comment: So $q$ is still $\min(4,p)$? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes. Theoretically min(3,p), but to see this in application you would need some kind of fractal function like a wavelet, with a nowhere differentiable third derivative on the right side to get any different result.